# A symmetry of the Hodge star operator

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, inner-products, hodge-theory

Theorem 1.3.2(i) on p. 7 of [these notes on the Hodge decomposition](https://nikno.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/hodge.pdf) states

> $$ * \eta \wedge w = \langle \eta, w \rangle _{\wedge^k V} dV .$$

I don't see how this holds. We defined the Hodge $*$ operator as the unique map $*:\wedge^kV \rightarrow \wedge^{n-k}V $ such that 
$$  w \wedge * \eta = \langle w, \eta \rangle_{\wedge^k V} dV. $$ 
Perhaps I am missing something obvious...

Comment: As far as I can tell, the author correctly writes $\ast \eta \wedge \omega = \langle \eta, \omega \rangle_{\wedge^k V} \, dV$ etc., etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a typo. (Indeed, if $\dim V$ is even and $\omega$ and $\eta$ are odd-degree forms, then $\ast \eta$ has odd degree, too, and $\omega \wedge \ast \eta = - \ast \eta \wedge \omega$.)

The identity in Theorem 1.3.2.1 should instead read
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\eta \wedge \ast \omega = \langle \eta, \omega \rangle_{\Lambda^k V} dV = \langle \omega, \eta \rangle_{\Lambda^k V} dV = \omega \wedge \ast \eta}} .$$ The first and third equalities follow from the characterization of $\ast$ that you mention, and the middle equality is just the symmetry of the induced bilinear form $\langle \,\cdot\, , \,\cdot \, \rangle_{\Lambda^k V}$.

Comment: Thanks travis, agreed. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found the answer helpful.